# Position of ScrollView not consistent in main view

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I have a scrollview with an HStack inside it that is sized according to how many hexagons are to be placed in it. There are three possible values - 25, 64 and 100. The scrollview is positioned correctly for 25 and 64 hexagons, but is shifted to the right for 100. How can I make sure that is centred correctly too?

Incidentally, I have already tried manually setting the position of the scrollview - it worked the same as without.

[image: App with 64 hexagons]
[image: App with 100 hexagons]

```
GeometryReader
{ scrollViewGeometry in
    ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal], showsIndicators: true)
    {
        Spacer()
        HStack(spacing:-(max(minHexagonSize, smallSide)))
        {
            ForEach(viewModel.hexagons){hexagon in
                let hexagonFrame = getFrameFor(hexagon: hexagon, minWidth: smallSide)
                let colorArray = getColorsFor(hexagon: hexagon)
                ZStack()
                {
                    let thisIndex = hexagon.id
                    HexagonView(strokeColor: colorArray[0]).onTapGesture(perform: {
                        viewModel.chooseHexagon(hexagon: hexagon)
                    })
                    .scaleEffect(hexagon.pressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
                    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))
                    if hexagon.isSelected
                    {
                        Circle().fill(playerColorArray[hexagon.playerIndex]).frame(width: hexagonFrame.width * fontScalingFactor, height: hexagonFrame.height * fontScalingFactor, alignment: .center)
                        Circle().stroke(Color.black).frame(width: hexagonFrame.width * fontScalingFactor, height: hexagonFrame.height * fontScalingFactor, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Text(verbatim: String(thisIndex+1)).font(Font.system(size: hexagonFrame.size.width * fontScalingFactor)).foregroundColor(colorArray[1])
                        .onTapGesture(perform: {
                            Sounds.playSounds(soundName: "pop")
                                viewModel.chooseHexagon(hexagon: hexagon)
                        })
                        .scaleEffect(hexagon.pressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
                        .animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.5))
                    }
                    if hexagon.isSelected && hexagon.pressed
                    {
                        Text(String(viewModel.currentScore))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .font(Font.system(size: hexagonFrame.size.width * fontScalingFactor)).foregroundColor(colorArray[1])
                            .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: AnyTransition.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity).animation(.easeIn(duration: 1.0))))
                            .animation(.easeIn(duration: 1.0))
                            .zIndex(hexagon.isSelected ? 1 : 0)
                    }
                }
                .position(x: hexagonFrame.origin.x - (scrollViewGeometry.size.width/2), y: scrollViewGeometry.size.height/2 - hexagonFrame.origin.y)
                .frame(width: hexagonFrame.size.width, height: hexagonFrame.size.height)
                .zIndex(hexagon.isSelected ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: (max(minHexagonSize, smallSide)) * (sqrt(CGFloat(viewModel.hexagons.count)) * 2), height: (max(minHexagonSize, smallSide) * (sqrt(CGFloat(viewModel.hexagons.count)) + 2)))
        //.position(x: scrollViewGeometry.size.width, y: scrollViewGeometry.size.height)
    }
    .padding()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK... so it turns out that the reason it was not centred, is because I was looking at the wrong part of the view. I still don't understand why it worked fine for the smaller scrollable areas in the scrollview, but not for the larger one!